# How does one get WinForms RichTextBox to paint lines correctly without having to highlight them?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox` functioning as a console into which I append a large number of lines in a short space of time, perhaps a few hundred as fast as possible. Only the first and last lines in the text box area are visible, and the remainder are painted white until highlighted or scrolled over and back to.

[image: before highlighting]

[image: after highlighting]

I have tried to use `this.console.Invalidate();` to force a repaint, and the following code to pause painting before and after to mitigate this issue but it remains present.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

const int WM_SETREDRAW = 0x000B;
HandleRef console = new HandleRef(this.console, this.console.Handle);

SendMessage(console, WM_SETREDRAW, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
/// print many lines
SendMessage(console, WM_SETREDRAW, new IntPtr(1), IntPtr.Zero);
```

Is this erroneous behaviour or is my code incorrect in some way?

Comment: I don't think RTB likes owner drawing, just like TextBox doesn't.

Comment: I don't really know what that means, how have I done "owner drawing"? I only added these extra paint controls because of the buggy rendering, prior to that all I did was `AppendText` in a loop, and it had the exact same rendering problems.

Comment: Yes, any code in the Paint event is at least to some extent 'owner-drawing'.  Legacy controls are not well suported for this, I'm afraid, which is another way of calling it a bug  :-)

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with ownerdraw.  It is very curious that RTB doesn't have this feature built-in, but I proposed this solution many years ago and never heard a complaint.  Being forced to guess, I'd say you're doing this from a worker thread.

Comment: No this is the only thread in the program, the one for the form itself. I'm just learning the ropes and decided to pump in the names and process id's of all the processes on my system to give it something non-deterministic and this was the behaviour when I added it all with `AppendText` in a loop.